# Convert dbnull to string. Record dbnull.value in database instead of Nothing

Tags: sql, vb.net, string, dbnull

I have an insertRecord function in vb.net that uses a parameter query. If there is no error date given, I need to insert dbnull.value into the db instead of ""(Nothing).

```
Dim strErrorDate2 As DateTime = Request.Form("dateOfErrorDatePicker2").ToString

.Add(New SqlParameter("@ErrorDate2", If(strErrorDate2 <> Nothing, strErrorDate2.Date, DBNull.Value)))
```

I keep getting conversion errors on dbnull to string. Originally it had it's own if/else block where I initialized the variable, but I couldn't figure out how to convert it correctly. I tried the inline if, but I still need to do a conversion or try something else.

Any ideas? The problem is that when I insert an empty string or DateTime into the database it records as a min possible date such as 1/1/1900.

EDIT: "Cannot infer a common type, 'object' assumed." That's the error I'm currently getting.

Comment: What happens if you just pass in `Nothing`?

Comment: If I pass in Nothing it also sets to a minimum date.

Comment: I suggest you put `Option Strict On` as the first line of the file with that code in. Then, when you have fixed the problems it highlights, your code may be in a working state :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because strErrorDate2.Date is a DateTime and System.DbNull.Value is an object. Either Direct Cast strErrorDate2 to object in the IF() or do something like this

```
Dim oErrorDate2 as Object = System.DbNull.Value

If strErrorDate2 <> Nothing Then oErrorDate = strErrorDate2

.Add(New SqlParameter("@ErrorDate2",oErrorDate2))
```

Comment: I ended up using a variable like above for DbNull.Value. I ran into problems trying to convert my input strings to DateTime when input was "", so I did an if to check if it's nothing. I convert to DateTime if there's something there, if not I use the DbNull variable as my parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly happening because of what is on your SQL Server side.  It is very likely that either you are calling a stored procedure that is replacing the Null with a minimum date, or else (more likely) the table that you are inserting into has either a Trigger or a Default column value that is assigning a minimum date when it is Null.

---

Just to clarify: First, you shouldn't have to worry about turning Nothing into DBNulls, ADO.net should be doing that for you.

Secondly, if you send SQL Server Nothing/Null and it stores something else, then that's because it (the table or the stored procedure) is replacing the NULL with a default value.  This is most likely because  the data design does not want NULLs to be in the column that you are trying to insert them to.

Comment: If pass in DBNull.Value it works correctly. I just can't figure out the logic of correctly deciding between the actual value and DBNull. Do you still think it's something SQL server side?

Comment: I'm confused.  In your OP you state that you get a string conversion error when you pass in DBNull.Value?

Comment: .Add(New SqlParameter("@ErrorDate2", strErrorDate2))    .Add(New SqlParameter("@ErrorDate2", DBNull.Value)) The first one works, but sets to a minimum date if isNothing. The second one works to insert null regardless.

Comment: And what happens if you do: `.Add(New SqlParameter("@ErrorDate2", Nothing))`?

Comment: .Add(New SqlParameter("@ErrorDate2", If(strErrorDate2 <> Nothing, strErrorDate2.Date, DBNull.Value))) - I'm trying to do both with this. This is where I receive an error.

Comment: Nothing also sets to a minimum, just like the variable equaling "" does.

Comment: No, try it the way that I wrote it above.  What happens then?

Comment: OK, then it's almost certainly what I said above in my answer.

Comment: .Add(New SqlParameter("@ErrorDate2", Nothing)) does the same thing as .Add(New SqlParameter("@ErrorDate2", strErrorDate2)) when strErrorDate2 has no value.