# Converting Empty String to NULL Double

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have spent much of the day trying to find an answer for this one.  I figured it would be easy but nothing is specific to what I am trying to do.  So I hope someone can help.

I am bringing values over from one system to another.  I have a few fields that come over as strings but they need to go into the new system as DOUBLE.  The problem occurs when there are empty strings ("") and it is trying to store this as double.  I have tried EVERYTHING.

```
dbnull.value
Double.TryParse
CDBL()
Double?
VAL()
```

etc...cannot get this to work and I am not sure why.

so here is the code:

```
Dim specvertclr As String = dt23.Rows(0).ItemArray.GetValue(38).ToString()
```

then when I insert this into my database I get the error because the field type is NUMERIC and I am trying to insert ""

I did have this working:

```
 Dim specvertclr As String

                        If dt23.Rows(0).ItemArray.GetValue(38).ToString() = "" Then
                            specvertclr = CStr(0)
                        Else
                            specvertclr = dt23.Rows(0).ItemArray.GetValue(38).ToString()
                        End If
```

But the problem with this is it inserts a 0 value and 0 is not the same as NULL. I want the NUMERIC field in my destination database (SQLCE) to be EMPTY when the string is empty from the source database.

Any help?

This is what I tried:

```
 Dim specvertclr As Nullable(Of Double) = CType(dt23.Rows(0).ItemArray.GetValue(38).ToString(), Double?)
```

and then my insert is basic and the program throws an error before it even gets here.  I know this part is correct.

```
  Dim cmd2 As SqlCeCommand = conn.CreateCommand()
                            cmd2.CommandText = "Insert into [Attr_Bridge] ([VERTCLR])  VALUES (?)"
                            With cmd2.Parameters
  .AddWithValue("P1", specvertclr)
end with
```

Comment: look at Double.TryParse - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Strings are not numbers. _specvertclr_ is a string. You need to use a [nullable double var](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I tried that too and I got the following error: Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid.

Comment: Well post the code where you use that nullable double. And the code used to insert it in the database

Comment: okay edited my post to include the part I tried

Comment: I think this may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13864696/convert-dbnull-to-string-record-dbnull-value-in-database-instead-of-nothing?rq=1

Comment: Yes that had the answer thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the content of your string before adding it to the database

```
Dim specvertclr = dt23.Rows(0).ItemArray.GetValue(38).ToString() 
....
Dim cmd2 As SqlCeCommand = conn.CreateCommand()
cmd2.CommandText = "Insert into [Attr_Bridge] ([VERTCLR])  VALUES (@P1)"
With cmd2.Parameters
   .Add("@P1", SqlDbType.Float).Value = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(specvertclr), DBNull.Value, CType(specvertclr, Object))
```

Comment: what would I use as the type ... SqlDbtype.Float?  There is no double option.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't look like it will work ...it says it is expecting a parameter that I am not supplying.

Comment: My insert statement still has something wrong with it.  For the purpose of this example I trimmed it down to 1 parameter because that was the only problem - everything else was going into the database just fine.  Now that I fixed that one parameter it says there is something wrong with parameter #1.  I will post the whole thing in my original question and tell me if you see anything wrong with it...I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be the answer .... Thank You Arminius for your linked article that lead me to right answer ... Thank you Steve for your time and help!

```
 Dim specvertclr As String = dt23.Rows(0).ItemArray.GetValue(38).ToString()

                    Dim oerrorspec As Object = System.DBNull.Value

                    If specvertclr <> Nothing Then oerrorspec = specvertclr
```

and then in the parameters section I used this

```
.Add(New SqlCeParameter("@P41", oerrorspec))
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question because I had the same issue. I was creating an app and one of the inputs was optional and I didn't want users to worry about putting zero so they don't receive an error. So my question was how to convert "" string to double? I came up with the below:

Dim Nontaxable As Double

```
        If txtNontaxable.Text IsNot "" Then

            Nontaxable = CDbl(txtNontaxable.Text)

        Else
            txtNontaxable.Text = 0

        End If
```

if the string isn't blank, it will be converted fine, if its blank, it will be replaced with zero, and then it will be converted fine. Hope this helps anyone had the same issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).